# How to wait for multiple threads to terminate in delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have an application with 50 threads that do something and I want my procedure (btnTestClick) to wait until all threads are terminated. I've tried with global variable as counter and with `WaitForMultipleObjects(threadCount, @threadArr, True, INFINITE);` but the procedure never waits for all threads to terminate.Here is how my thread looks like :

```
TClientThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor create(isSuspended : Boolean = False);
end;
```

And here are the **constructor** and the **execute** procedure :

```
constructor TClientThread.create(isSuspended : Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(isSuspended);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var
begin
  inherited;
  criticalSection.Enter;
  try
    Inc(globalThreadCounter);
  finally
    criticalSection.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

And my OnButtonClick is this :

```
procedure TMainForm.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  clientThreads : array of TClientThread;
  i, clientThreadsNum : Integer;
begin
  clientThreadsNum := 50;
  SetLength(clientThreads, clientThreadsNum);
  for i := 0 to Length(clientThreads) - 1 do begin // РЕДАКТИРАЙ !!
    clientThreads[i] := TClientThread.Create(True);
  end;
  // here I will assign some variables to the suspended threads, but that's not important here 
  for i := 0 to Length(clientThreads) - 1 do begin
    clientThreads[i].Start;
  end;

  WaitForMultipleObjects(clientThreadsNum, @clientThreads, True, INFINITE);
  // do something after all threads are terminated 
end;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You code reads:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(clientThreadsNum, @clientThreads, True, INFINITE);
```

where `clientThreads` is of type:

```
array of TClientThread
```

Now, `@clientThreads` is the address of the dynamic array. That is the address of a pointer to the first thread object. But you are expected to pass a pointer to the first thread handle, something utterly different. So instead you need to form a list of thread handles:

```
var
  ThreadHandles: array of THandle;
....
SetLength(ThreadHandles, Length(clientThreads));
for i := 0 to high(clientThreads) do
  ThreadHandles[i] := clientThreads[i].Handle;
WaitForMultipleObjects(clientThreadsNum, Pointer(ThreadHandles), True, INFINITE);
```

You would have discovered that your call to `WaitForMultipleObjects` was incorrect had you checked the return value. A basic rule of Win32 programming, one that you should strive not to break, is that you check the values returned by function calls.

I believe that your call to `WaitForMultipleObjects` will return `WAIT_FAILED`. When that happens you can call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong. You should modify your code to perform proper error checking. Take good care to read the documentation to find out how to do so.